# Capturing string between 2 specific letters/words using shell scripting

Tags: string, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to capture the string between 2 specific letters/words using sed/awk. This is what I am trying to do:

The input is a file `test.log` containing

```
Owner: CN=abc.samplecerrt.com,o=IN,DC=com
Owner: CN=abc1.samplecerrt.com,o=IN,DC=com
```

I want to extract only "CN=abc.samplecerrt.com"

I tried

```
sed 's/.*CN=\(.*\),.*/\1/p' test.log >> result.log
```

But this returns "abc.samplecerrt.com,o=IN,DC=com"

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

test file:

```
$ cat logs.txt
CN=abc.samplecerrt.com,o=IN,DC=com Owner: CN=abc1.samplecerrt.com,o=IN,DC=com
```

command and output:

```
$ grep -oP 'CN=(?:(?!CN=).)*?.com' logs.txt
CN=abc.samplecerrt.com
CN=abc1.samplecerrt.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/.*\(CN=[^,]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

Or:

```
sed 's/.*\(CN=[^,]*\).*/\1/p;d' file
```

The first turns off implicit printing `-n` so as to act like grep.

Matches and captures the string `CN=` followed by zero or more non-comma characters and prints the captured group `\1` if a match is made.

The second solution is much the same except it deletes all lines and only prints the captured group as above.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you can get the field where is the string you need. For it, you can set `FS=:|,` Now if you run

```
awk -v FS=":|," '{print $2}' file
 CN=abc.samplecerrt.com
 CN=abc1.samplecerrt.com
```

you get the field. But you only want one, so

```
awk -v FS=":|," '$2 !~ /abc1/ {print $2}' file

 CN=abc.samplecerrt.com
```